# How to set div with image in it, outside the websites width, without scroller to appear?

Tags: css, html, width, overflow, scroller

I have a website with two `div`s aside the main body, on the left and right side, and both of them have images which are approximately `500px` in width, combined with the main body width of `980px` (it makes them larger than any normal screen resolution).

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="#brandLeft">..</div>
    <div id="#brandRight">..</div>
    <div id="#mainbody">..</div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#brandLeft {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 890px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1010px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 171px;
    width: 350px;
}

#brandRight {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 890px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: -835px;
    top: 171px;
    width: 350px;
}
```

In the `body` I've already set the `overflow-x: hidden`, so I don't see the vertical scroll bar, but the page is still scrollable with the arrows and with the mouse center button.

I can't use jQuery to disable the scrolling so I was wondering if there's a way to have the `div`s with the large images, without having a scroll bar on the website?

Answer (score 0):

Your images are to big for the side bars, so try this.
Remove the width and height of your images from the actual html.
Control the width/height of the images by using something like..

```
#brandleft, #brandright img {
width:100%;
}
```

Doing somethign like that should scale your images to the size of the Divs on the left and right side to get rid of the scroll bars.  If that doesn't work let me know.